# Python - split() producing ValueError

Tags: python, csv, split

I am trying to split the line:

`American plaice - 11,000 lbs @ 35 cents or trade for SNE stocks`

at the word `or` but I receive `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`.

Which doesn't make sense, if I split the sentence at `or` then that will indeed leave 2 sides, not 1.

Here's my code:

```
if ('-' in line) and ('lbs' in line):
    fish, remainder = line.split('-') 
    if 'trade' in remainder:
        weight, price = remainder.split('to ')
        weight, price = remainder.split('or')
```

The `'to'` line is what I normally use, and it has worked fine, but this new line appeared without a `'to'` but instead an `'or'` so I tried writing one line that would tackle either condition but couldn't figure it out so I simply wrote a second and am now running into the error listed above.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: There's isn't a `'to '` in that line

Comment: I know, that's why I added the line below it with `'or'`....which is the line it fails on, even when I comment out the `'to'` line

Comment: I actually got too many items to unpack.. the remainder splits on **'or'** and 'f**or**'

Comment: your error is that when trying to split first on 'to ', it returns a list of length 1, which cannot be unpacked into weight and price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You split on `'to '` before you attempt to split on `'or'`, which is throwing the error. The return value of `remainder.split('to ')` is `[' 11,000 lbs @ 35 cents or trade for SNE stocks']` which cannot be unpacked to two separate values. you can fix this by testing for which word you need to split on first.

```
if ('-' in line) and ('lbs' in line):
    fish, remainder = line.split('-') 
    if 'trade' in remainder:
        if 'to ' in remainder:
            weight, price = remainder.split('to ')
        elif ' or ' in remainder:
            weight, price = remainder.split(' or ') #add spaces so we don't match 'for'
```

Comment: Ok I gotcha. I didn't think `'or'` would also capture `'for'` but it makes sense that it does. Thanks for the help and the explanation, it was really clear

Comment: @theprowler I missed the spaces for 'or' in the if statement as well... see edit

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward way is probably to use a regular expression to do the split. Then you can split on either word, whichever appears. The `?:` inside the parentheses makes the group non-capturing so that the matched word doesn't appear in the output.

```
import re
# ...
weight, price = re.split(" (?:or|to) ", remainder, maxsplit=1)
```

Comment: Ohhh gotcha I didn't think it would be that simple using RegEx to do this. Running that line of code though produced a syntax error saying `keyword can't be an expression`

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem by checking if your separator is in the string first.

Also note that `split(str, 1)` makes sure that your list will be split a max of one time (Ex `"hello all world".split(" ", 1) == ["hello", "all world"]`)

```
if ('-' in line) and ('lbs' in line):
    fish, remainder = line.split('-') 
    if 'trade' in remainder:
        weight, price = remainder.split(' to ', 1) if ' to ' in remainder else remainder.split(' or ', 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have done the `split()`, you have a list, not a string.  So you can not do another `split()`.  And if you just copy the line, then you will overwrite you other results. You can instead try and do the processing as a string:

```
weight, price = remainder.replace('or ', 'to ').split('to ')
```

Comment: Are you sure? Because in the rest of my code (which I didn't add above) I do in fact do several splits after each other without an error.... I am a novice and I'm not telling you you're wrong but I can assure you my code works using `split()` several times in a row. Also, I tried your line of code and it failed :( it produced `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: If you got too many things to unpack, it means that there was more than one `'to '` and `'or '`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the word "for" also contains an "or" therefore you will end up with the following:

```
a = 'American plaice - 11,000 lbs @ 35 cents or trade for SNE stocks'
a.split('or')
```

gives

```
['American plaice - 11,000 lbs @ 35 cents ', ' trade f', ' SNE stocks']
```

Stephen Rauch's answer does fix the problem